# Sheet dismiss gesture with swipe back gesture causes app to freeze

Tags: ios, swiftui

I found a strange and frustrating behavior in SwiftUI. If you present a sheet from within a view in a navigation link and then (quickly and in order):

1. swipe down to dismiss the sheet
2. swipe back (from left edge to the right) to dismiss the navigation view

The app will freeze before going back to the root view. Backgrounding the app and foregrounding it will unstick it.

You have to perform the steps very quickly.
Is there a workaround? I would like both gestures to work without interfering with each other.

This code will reproduce the issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("blah") {
                    VStack {
                        Button("Show Sheet") {
                            showSheet.toggle()
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: nil) {
                            Text("Sheet")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a gif of the issue in the simulator. First showing the issue, then showing that if you background the app, it resolves on it's own.

[image]

**EDIT: Oct 2022**: This bug is still present in iOS 16

**EDIT: Sep 2023**: This bug is still present in iOS 17

Comment: @xTwisteDx thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately that didn't work. `toggle` will cause the sheet to re-appear immediately I think because `showSheet` is implicitly toggled when the sheet is dismissed by the gesture. 

I also tried setting `showSheet` it to `false` in `onDismiss`, but the bug persists.

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this with the given code. This might be an issue with your simulator, try resetting it or reproducing on a real device.

Comment: @xTwisteDx I can reproduce this on a real device (and it is also present in my app on the App Store). It was also not resolved between iOS 15.3 and 15.4. Note in order to reproduce you have to move very quickly (it's especially difficult to reproduce with a mouse on the simulator) - much easier on a real device.

Comment: Same issue. It's 100% reproducible (iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 16 at least). You need to dismiss the modal view with a gesture (swipe-down-to-dismiss) and then try to do a swipe-to-back gesture REALLY QUICK. Eventually, you will catch this. I think it happens because the modal view could be not finished with dismissing when you started swipe-to-back gesture.

Comment: Did you find the solution, OP?

Comment: Also, Apple's native SwiftUI apps have this issue, like Podcasts (on iOS 16 it's made with SwiftUI, I don't know about older versions)

Comment: @surfrider Still no workaround. Also thanks for mentioning this occurs in an Apple app. I have been trying to reproduce this in several system apps, but could not find the unique combination of a sub-navigation view + a sheet. Good to know it exists there too. 

I am not sure how to escalate this further unfortunately. However I will do my best to keep this post up to date if I learning anything.

Comment: Yes, I reproduced it in all the mentioned apps :) I guess the only way to avoid it (in theory, I didn't try to implement it) is to track when model is shown and hidden, and enable/disable swipe-to-pop gesture in these moments. For latter, you need to interact with UIKit in some way to get access to UINavigationController.

Comment: I also encountered the same bug, I guess as @surfrider said we’ll need to toggle the swipe back manually. I’m thinking about disabling the back button completely with the navigation modifier while the state of the modal is true. I’ll keep you updated on how it goes

Comment: @Hiimdjango I believe that the right way to do it - is not to do it. Because it's a bug of SwiftUI itself, not worth the time to fix, eventually it will be fixed by Apple.

Comment: I have the same problem with in my UIKit app. And also I managed to reproduce it in Apple Music and Files apps. Not sure if they are UIKit or SwiftUI. The key steps to reproduce is the same: swipe-down to dismiss sheet (modal), then swipe-back and do this quickly. iOS 16.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed as fixed on iOS 17.2.1 (FB12402900).

Answer (score 0):

I explain the cause and solution of this problem in this post
[Common Pitfalls Caused by Delayed State Updates in SwiftUI](https://betterprogramming.pub/serious-issues-caused-by-delayed-state-updates-in-swiftui-76ffd8431c5a)

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var showSheet = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("GO") {
                VStack {
                    Button("Show Sheet") {
                        showSheet.toggle()
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                        Text("Sheet")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .overlay(
        Group {
            if showSheet {
                Color.white.opacity(0.01)
                    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0))
            }
        }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This does actually appear to work. However it's not exactly an ideal workaround. Thanks